# Use value from cell to determine other cell

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I get value from cell by using

```
Number = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CRMv1").Cells(2, 10).Value
```

When I have Number, I want to use it to choose the next cell, by indexing by this val.

Like

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NEXT CONTATCT").Cells(**Number, 2**).Value
= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CRMv1").Cells(13, 1).Value
```

Can anyone help me to fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) or simply add/subtract from **Number**.

```
'add 1 to Number to locate one row below
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NEXT CONTATCT").Cells(Number + 1, 2) = _
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CRMv1").Cells(13, 1).Value

'Offset 1 row below
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NEXT CONTATCT").Cells(Number, 2).Offset(1, 0) = _
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CRMv1").Cells(13, 1).Value
```